# React Native - Android - Splash Screen flashing during App navigation

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I am developing a React Native application, and on Android, I have the problem that the splash screen flashes when I am navigating through different pages in the App.

I've tried to modify the .XML files to set the background color, I tried to style the whole app with a set solid background color but nothing works. Basically, I tried every solution available online, with no success.
Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Hey Edoardo! Would be best if you share  relevan code snippets or a screen recording.

Answer (score 2):

set this `animationEnabled: false` in screenOptions

```
 <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ animationEnabled: false }}   >
    ....
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: This is a useful answer as it does work but it should be possible to enable animations without showing the splash screen!

Comment: was looking for something else, but your solution help me in fixing another issue.